# Silent Disco Equipment

Tags: audio, wireless

I get quote from my client to make event with **Silent Disco**
What is the hardware required for Silent Disco?

Here is some link referral, but I'm looking advise from expertise have done this.

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_disco
2. http://silentdisco.com/v2/

Comment: I would suggest you contact the vendor for specifics about hardware requirements.  They'll know best.

Comment: Do you need an act or just the equipment. There are companies that do shows or companies that just ship equipment. They may know what equipment you need.. Try searching for silent disco kit on google.

Comment: i need the equipment.